# Extender asp.net mvc 5 identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo que armar un sistema de login y que dicho sistema que se pueda reutilizar en dos proyectos mvc

El modelo (segun la arquitectura) quedo de la siguiente manera:

- **Usuario**: usu, contraseña, emailConfirmado, etc
- **Cliente**: usuarioId, email, etc.
- **Empleado**: usuarioId, email, etc.

A su vez, el modelo tiene otras tablas para la seguridad:

- **Usuario_Permiso**: usuarioId, permisoId
- **Permiso**: permisoId, desc
- **Rol_Permiso**: rolId, permisoId
- **Rol**: rolId, desc
- **Usuario_Rol**: usuarioId, rolId

Mi pregunta es ¿es recomendable extender el `asp.net mvc5 identity` o es preferible utilizar mi propio sistema de login?

Saludos

Answer (score 2):

En mi opinión te diría rotundamente si, usar **ASP.NET Identity** te va a aportar muchas ventajas, despreocupándote de las tareas criptográficas y ahorrándote trabajo. Además, **ASP.NET Identity** está preparada para ser extendida porque, de una forma sencilla se puede cambiar desde el tipo de los identificadores hasta usar tus propias entidades de `usuarios`, `roles`, ...

Creo que en tu caso solo necesitas ponerla en común, añadir un sistema de autorización y enlazar las entidades de `usuarios` con las de `clientes` y `empleados`

Una forma sencilla de hacerlo sería creando un proyecto de `Biblioteca de clases` e ir moviendo los elementos de **ASP.NET Identity** que se incluyen, por defecto, en el proyecto de MVC (`ApplicationUser`, `ApplicationDbContext`, `ApplicationUserManager`, ...).

Después, añadirías los elementos necesarios para gestionar la autorización (entidades para definir los permisos, servicio para gestionar la autorización, ...)

En mi opinión, la asociación entre `usuarios` y `clientes` y `empleados` no la incluiría en el proyecto común porque así te podría servir para mas proyectos en los que no tengas estas entidades.

Y por último, si empaquetas este proyecto en un paquete **NuGet** podrías, de una forma sencilla, añadir autenticación y autorización a todos tus proyectos.

En este artículo de CodeProject "[ASP.NET Identity with webforms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/751897/ASP-NET-Identity-with-webforms)" puedes ver la flesibilidad de **ASP.NET Identity** que hasta se puede *"pinchar"* en un proyecto de `WebForms`

Answer (score 1):

Identity hace uso de `Entity Framework` para implementar la persistencia de las entidades que define, lo cual nos permite aplicar herencia a la hora de extender su funcionalidad.

[Extending ASP.net Identity in an ASP.net MVC 5 application](http://aspmvp.com/archives/37)

Se puede empezar con algo simple, por ejemplo, agregar una propiedad al usuario

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Email { get; set; } 
}
```

La clase hereda de `IdentityUser` la cual define la estructura de la tabla `AspNetUser`

[ASP.NET MVC 5: Extending ASP.NET Identity 2.0 Roles and Implementation of Role Based Authorization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/799571/ASP-NET-MVC-Extending-ASP-NET-Identity-Roles)

Pero tambien puedes extender los demas objetos definidos en el modelo de Identity, como ser el rol, añadiendo una nueva propiedad.

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Como estaras entendiendo solo es cuestion de aplicar herencia, pero por tratarse de EF puede tambien puedes definir el contexto para personalizar como mapear estas nuevas propiedades a los campos de la db

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }
}
```

Otra ventaja que se obtienes al usar `EF` es que puedes aplicar `migrations` para actualizar la estructura de datos que has definido.